# Shooting many bullets toward the mouse position

Tags: c++, mathematics, sfml

I try to shoot a bullet toward the mouse position by this code.

```
float deltaX = mousePosition.x - (aircraft.getPosition().x + aircraft.getLocalBounds().width / 2);
float deltaY = mousePosition.y - (aircraft.getPosition().y + aircraft.getLocalBounds().height / 2);
float angleRadian = (float)(std::atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
float angleDegree = (float)(angleRadian * 180 / PI);
```

It works fine with one bullet but when I add another one bullet to shoot together I use this code to specify start shooting point of each bullets.

```
sf::Vector2f offset1(aircraft.getPosition());
offset1.x += -10;//start shooting point first bullet.

sf::Vector2f offset2(aircraft.getPosition());
offset2.x += 10;//start shooting point second bullet.
```

this is a picture of this problem.
[image]

When I rotate aircraft to picture 2 the bullets are not the same as the first picture.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather easy using the buit-in transforms:

```
float hoffset = ...; // This is the horizontal offset for the gun

sf::Transform rotation;
rotation.rotate(angle); // This is essentially the ship's rotation

// This will get you the offsets relative to the ship's position
sf::Vector2f bulletOffsetLeft(rotation.transformPoint(-hoffset, 0.f));
sf::Vector2f bulletOffsetRight(rotation.transformPoint(hoffset, 0.f));
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems rather straightforward, you need to consider the ships rotation, lets assume that picture 1 is the 0° rotation, then your offsets would be;

```
sf::Vector2f offset1(aircraft.getPosition());
offset1.x += 10 * sin(deg2rad(aircraft.getRotation()+180));
offset1.y += 10 * cos(deg2rad(aircraft.getRotation()+180);

sf::Vector2f offset2(aircraft.getPosition());
offset2.x += 10 * sin(deg2rad(aircraft.getRotation()));
offset2.y += 10 * cos(deg2rad(aircraft.getRotation()));
```

with deg2rad being

```
inline double deg2rad( double degrees){
    return degrees * pi / 360;
}
```

where you get `pi` from is up to you, either use `M_PI` by using `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before including `<cmath>` or just use a `#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884` in your code.

Comment: Actually, the second picture is the 0 degree rotation.

Comment: Then you can change every `.x` to a `.y` and vice versa. But you should probably do it like @Mario suggested and use the sfml api instead of mixing it with `<cmath>` like I did.

Comment: Or you know, get the difference and normalize. Then multiply it by desired speed. They are vectors, their properties make life easier.

Comment: Ok, I guess I forgot SF::Vector2f don't have those properties...Eh OP should probably find a good Vector2D header for that.

Comment: @Sidar that's not what the question is about anyways, it's not about the actual traveling projectiles, it's about calculating the starting point based on the rotation of the starship. Basically it's a simple "how to rotate these offsets" question.

Comment: I guess I misread it.